# Include common ejs view files with partial amendment for each different view files?

Tags: node.js, express, include, ejs

I am using nodejs express with ejs view engine, and I wonder if there is anyway to include common ejs view files with partial amendment for each different view files.

It is hard for me to explain my situation, so I will do my best.

I have 5 view files, and those files must include the same code below.

Below is the code.

```
<div class="sub-content-company_intro">
    <div class="l-common-wrapper">
    <div class="company-name">
      <span style="font-weight: bold">test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="l-sub-content-main-menu-outer">
        <ul class="l-sub-content-main-menu-row">
          <li class="l-sub-content-main-menu-col col-5">
            <a class="item active" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
          <li>
          <li class="l-sub-content-main-menu-col col-5">
            <a class="item" href="/dealing_works/item2">item2</a>
          <li>
          <li class="l-sub-content-main-menu-col col-5">
            <a class="item" href="/dealing_works/item3">item3</a>
          <li>
          <li class="l-sub-content-main-menu-col col-5">
            <a class="item" href="/dealing_works/item4">item4</a>
          <li>
          <li class="l-sub-content-main-menu-col col-5">
            <a class="item last" href="/dealing_works/item5">item5</a>
          <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here comes my issue.

The difference between the first view file and second view file, is that
the code above is partially different.

```
// first view file
<a class="item active" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
<a class="item" href="/dealing_works/item2">item2</a>

// second view file
<a class="item" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
<a class="item active" href="/dealing_works/item2">item2</a>
```

Same with the third, fourth, fifth ejs view files.

I used to use

```
<%= include something %>
```

But since I have to change the code partially, facing some difficulties.

Do I have to copy and paste all those codes for each five view files?

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables into EJS templates:

```
res.render('dealing_works/item1', { page: 'item1' });
```

You can reference these variables in EJS included files, as well:

```
<a class="item <% if ( page === 'item1' ) { -%>active<% } -%>" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
<a class="item <% if ( page === 'item2' ) { -%>active<% } -%>" href="/dealing_works/item2">item2</a>
```

Edit:

It's kind of ugly, but I don't actually take the above approach on my page, I do this instead:

```
<a id="link_page1" class="item" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
<a id="link_page2" class="item" href="/dealing_works/item2">item2</a>
```

In the main file:

```
<%= include something %>
<code type="text/javascript">
  Document.getElementById('link_page1').classList.add('active');
</code>
```

Edit 2:

Regarding the `<%  -%>` tag delimeters; the opening one just being `<%` means that the code in the tag doesn't produce any output.  I'll give an example below where we might want this to be the case.

The last tag can be `%>` but this injects a newline, the resolved HTML would look like this, I think:

```
<a class="item 
" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
```

By changing `%>` to `-%>`, that newline goes away, and your resulting HTML looks a lot cleaner.

We could redo the solution to use tags that output, if we did this:

```
res.render('dealing_works/item1', { page1class: 'active' });
```

Now, if we reference these variables using the `<%-` opening tag (there's also `<%=`)

```
<a class="item <%- page1class -%>" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
<a class="item <%- page2class -%>" href="/dealing_works/item2">item2</a>
```

But, unless you define page2class as an empty string, your html might look like this:

```
<a class="item active" href="/dealing_works/item1">item1</a>
<a class="item undefined" href="/dealing_works/item2">item2</a>
```

Comment: This is magic. Thank you so much.


I am now searching what the -%> is, and ejs doc says
"-%> Trim-mode ('newline slurp') tag, trims following newline"

and I am confusing with
<% if ( page === 'item2' ) { -%>active<% } -%>"
between
<% if ( page === 'item2' ) { -%>active-%> } %>"

Comment: There's some weird formatting things going on, so I'll demo it a bit in the answer with an edit.

Comment: Appreciated it !